How to Determine the Optimal Number of Clusters / distance threshold in Agglomerative Clustering Using a Connectivity Matrix?
I am working on agglomerative clustering with the goal of ensuring continuity among clusters. To achieve this, I am using a connectivity matrix to enforce certain continuity constraints. However, it is challenging to determine the optimal number of clusters in the data. Is there a method for finding the optimal number of clusters or a suitable distance threshold for this type of clustering problem?
The cluster output looks like the image below

n_samples = len(features_transformed)

# Creating a connectivity matrix to ensure continuity
connectivity = np.zeros((n_samples, n_samples))
for i in range(n_samples - 1):
    connectivity[i, i + 1] = 1
    connectivity[i + 1, i] = 1`

